# HBase get based on row postfix

Tags: hbase

Is there a way to form a GET based on row postfix?

For example, if I have rows such as:

x-y-z

Is there a way to form a GET, or at least SCAN which will return only one row, based on the z part of the key, not knowing the x-y part?

Comment: Have you tried RegexStringComparator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HBase filters to get the result based on filter query.

For you use case, you can use `Row Filter` with `RegexString` comparator or `Substring` comparator.

Refer [HBase Filters](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/client.filter.html)

Comment: I have tried RowFilter with RegexString, as a filter for SCAN. Unfortunately, this works terribly slow. Is there a way to speed up this operation? I basically need to go through most of the table and perform operation for each, but in a specific order, so I'm getting rows one by one as I need them.

Comment: Ok, I understood how to use it, but I'm worried about the performance. Anyway, I will accept your answer and if you can provide more info about ways to make this faster it would be great.

Comment: Usually some HBase filters are slow in performance. You can ask question in HBase  user mailing list user@hbase.apache.org to improve performance.

Comment: http://hbase.apache.org/mail-lists.html find all HBase mailing list here.